# How to get stored object array from local storage and display in the browser using java script

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to create a journal app that users can give titles and contents. this title and content save in the local storage as and later both need to display on the browser. I successfully did the storing part. however, when I trying to display title and content, it displays as undefined.

```
//html

<body onload="displayTodo()">
    <input type="text" name="" id="textTitle">
    <input type="text" name="" id="textContent">
    <button type="submit" id="add">add</button>

    <div id="display"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//java script
let textTitle = document.getElementById("textTitle");
let textContent = document.getElementById("textContent");
let display = document.getElementById('display');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', addToStorage);

function addToStorage() {
    let textTitleValue = textTitle.value;
    let textContentValue = textContent.value;
    // insert user inpurt into an abject array
    let notes = [{
        "title": textTitleValue,
        "content": textContentValue
    }]
    // get the exsisting jason data from the local storage and convert to string values
    let getNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary")) || [];
    // push the user input into the converted object array
    getNotes.push(notes);

    
    // convert string to json data
    let notes_s = JSON.stringify(getNotes);
    // send the json data in to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem("diary", notes_s);
    console.log(localStorage);

}

function displayTodo() {
    let notesObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary"));
    let newNotesObject = [];
newNotesObject.push(notesObject);

// console.log(newObjectFor);

    for (let i = 0; i < newNotesObject.length; i++) {
        console.log(newNotesObject[i]);

        let item = `
<li>
        <p class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">${newNotesObject[i].title}</p>
        <p class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">${newNotesObject[i].content}</p>
</li>

`
display.innerHTML += item;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new array each time you are adding any new object.
Updated JS:

```
let textTitle = document.getElementById("textTitle");
let textContent = document.getElementById("textContent");
let display = document.getElementById('display');

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', addToStorage);

function addToStorage() {
    let textTitleValue = textTitle.value;
    let textContentValue = textContent.value;
    // insert user inpurt into an abject array
    let notes = {
        "title": textTitleValue,
        "content": textContentValue
    };
    // get the exsisting jason data from the local storage and convert to string values
    let getNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary")) || [];
    // push the user input into the converted object array
    getNotes.push(notes);

    
    // convert string to json data
    let notes_s = JSON.stringify(getNotes);
    // send the json data in to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem("diary", notes_s);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("diary"));

}

function displayTodo() {
    let notesObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary"));

    for (let i = 0; i < notesObject.length; i++) {
        console.log(notesObject);

        let item = `
<li>
        <p class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">${notesObject[i].title}</p>
        <p class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">${notesObject[i].content}</p>
</li>

`
display.innerHTML += item;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is undefiend? can you provide the specific error?

Answer (score 0):

1. On page load **displayTodo** function is called and this function is taking title and content from local storage named as "diary" but at this point, there is no such storage named as "diary". So it will print undefined on page load
2. When button click **addToStorage**  function triggered. This function is taking data from a local-storage named "diary". But there is no data here till now in **diary** storage. So it will set undefined in localstorage.